# What does this PHP error mean? Call to undefined function addSlashesIfNeeded()

Tags: php

Getting this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function addSlashesIfNeeded() in **** on line 0

can someone tell me what this error means? and possibly a solution?

thank you.

Comment: It means that function does not exist. Can you show your code for that function?

Comment: that's not a standard php function, so it's probably in some module/library you've forgotten to load. and given th ename, it's probably not necessary anymore, and/or your code is hideously dated. addslashes is a garbage/useless function.

Comment: your error is on line zero?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Call to undefined function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115886/php-call-to-undefined-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your code calls a custom function called `addSlashesIfNeeded()` and your code isn't including for whatever reason. You need to find the file where that function is defined and include it in the page that is trying to call it.