# Fatal Errror: function is undefined | The function still does its job though?

Tags: php, function, fatal-error, undefined-function

I am getting a Fatal Error for a function that is cleared defined AND working correctly. Even though it does its job it still says that it is "undefined."
Has anyone experienced that before?

> /include/adminbar.php

```
<?php if (is_logged_in()) : ?>
    <div id="globaluserbar" class="gobaluseradminbar" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; background:#292929; height:42px; width:100%; color:white; vertical-align:middle;">This is the adminbar</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> /include/functions.php

```
function is_logged_in(){
        if (!empty($_SESSION[SESSION_IS_LOGGEDIN]) && $_SESSION[SESSION_IS_LOGGEDIN] == 1) {
            return true;
        } 
    }

function theme_header(){
    include URLBASE."/includes/theme-inc/head.php";
    include URLBASE."/content/themes/default/header.php";
}

function theme_footer(){
    include URLBASE."/content/themes/default/footer.php"; 
    include URLBASE."/includes/adminbar.php";
    include URLBASE."/includes/theme-inc/foot.php";
}
```

> /index.php

```
<?php theme_header(); ?>
<p>This is the main index!</p>
<?php theme_footer(); ?>
```

All the other stuff shouldn't have a factor.

the error states on the index.php that

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_logged_in() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ionz\2.0\includes\adminbar.php on line 1

Comment: Some code along with errors would help demystify this mystery.

Comment: I am working on a system that includes and requires a lot of php documents, how should I add them here?

Comment: Is there a particular line or file called out in the error?

Comment: Let's start with the error you get and the function definition in question.

Comment: There updated with all the stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this if both functions are in the same class, in which case you need to write:

```
if ($this->is_logged_in())
```

Or you could be missing a brace somewhere, which would make your function a nested function.  Take a look at this issue too:
[PHP Call to undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115886/php-call-to-undefined-function)